# Import-Export with "multilevel" models

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am figuring how can I manage this situation with django-import-export using the same excel and differents models with differents djangoapps. I have the following models:

```python
# employees/models.py
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

```python
# jobs/models.py
class Job(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

class Department(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

class Place(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

On excel I have following values:

```
xls_employee_name, xls_employee_job, xls_business_name
Jon Doe, Web Developer, Company 1
```

I know how to import employee name and his job because Job is directly related by ForeignKey. But how can I import business name?

Below is the code for employee name and his job:

```python
# employees/resource.py
class EmpleadoResource(resources.ModelResource):
    name = fields.Field(attribute='nombre', column_name='Nombre')    
 
        job = fields.Field(
            column_name='xls_employee_job',
            attribute='job',
            widget=ForeignKeyWidget(
                Job,
                field='value'
            ))

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('name','job',)
        skip_unchanged = True
        
        

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        self.job = row["xls_employee_job"]

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        Job.objects.get_or_create(name=self.job)
```

Is it possible to import business name using one excel? I appreciate if someone could guide me. I'm also pretty new with django.

Comment: Did you put the full descriptions of your file and your models? What prevents you from adding a FK for `Business model?`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand exactly what do you mean. I didn't create a business FK directly to employee because the design requires employee has a job and job is dependent of department and place and those both dependent of business. If employee has a Business FK it would be easier to create the code I'm trying. You can see my other comment to understand where is my "missing link"

Answer (score 1):

thank you for all your answers. I finally manage it and this is the solution(it was a little trickier for me, but very simple. I tried to translate all spanish names to english, sorry if I misslooked some):

```python
# employees/resource.py
class EmployeeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    name = fields.Field(attribute='name', column_name='Name')    
 
        job = fields.Field(
            column_name='xls_employee_job',
            attribute='job',
            widget=ForeignKeyWidget(
                Job,
                field='value'
            ))
    place = fields.Field(attribute='place', column_name='xls_place_column')
    department = fields.Field(attribute='department', column_name='xls_department_column')
    business = fields.Field(attribute='business', column_name='xls_business_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('name','job','place','department','business')
        skip_unchanged = True
        

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        self.job = row["xls_employee_job"]
        self.place = row["xls_place_column"]
        self.department = row["xls_department_column"]
        self.business = row["xls_business_name"]

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        Job.objects.get_or_create(name=self.job)
        Centro.objects.get_or_create(name=self.centro)
        Departamento.objects.get_or_create(name=self.departamento)
        Empresa.objects.get_or_create(nombre=self.empresa)
```

I was stucked using widgets for business, department and place, but it was not necessary

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

You can assign the column value for each row to a temporary attribute on the model (it doesn't matter that this attribute is not in the `Employee` model):

```py
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        self.job = row["xls_employee_job"]
        # assign row value to a temporary attr
        self.business = row["xls_business_name"]

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        Job.objects.get_or_create(name=self.job)
        # create instance using temp attr value
        Business.objects.get_or_create(name=self.business)
```

#### Option 2

You can create all `Business` instances by processing the dataset in a batch before processing the `Employee` resources:

```py
    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        for row in dataset.dict:
            business = row["xls_business_name"]
            Business.objects.create(name=business)
```

Note that you could use [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) here to make this process more efficient.

Add [transaction protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) as you see fit, and bear in mind that the `Business` and `Job` entities will be created even if your import fails.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but there is still a missing link for me. How do you declare attribute business on EmpleadoResource? business = fields.Field( column_name='xls_business_name', attribute=(business attribute is not an employee's attribute in models.py), widget=ForeignKeyWidget( Business, field='name' ))

Comment: you can use `business` as a temporary attr - python doesn't care that it is not a model attribute.  I also suggest an alternative option (process all rows in batch before the import)